# Catching early morning flight in Reykjavik

Tags: airports, reykjavik, wow-air

I am planning to book an early morning flight from Reykjavik to Berlin via `Wow air`, its departure time is 6:10 am.

How easy it is to reach Keflavik airport early, is it easy to get airport commute so early in morning?

I can see all Wow air Europe flights depart almost at similar times, so airport will be crowded, any idea at what should one plan to reach airport?

Edit:

Correct above, its Keflavik airport not Reykjavik but its the main airport for International flights.

Update:

I booked Grayline pickup for 3am and it dropped me at airport by 3:50am. I had no problems and reached the boarding area well in time and even submitted my tax refund form.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Super easy.

There are a ton of flights from 6am to 8am each and every morning. So the airport bus and other shuttle services all accommodate this.

For a 6am flight, I'd aim to get there at least 2 hours before departure. I might make it 1.5 hours if I was flying carry-on only. If flying during peak season (June-August), add 15-30 mins to be safe.

Comment: I used to arrive 2 hours in advance.  2-3 years ago that was fine, but Iceland has grown tremendendously in popularity at *any* time of year.  I found the terminal very crowded and that was less than two weeks ago, in the last week of September.  I would recommend 2½ hours.

Comment: @Kris: First shuttle [grayline or flybus] reaches airport earliest by 3:45. This will make it tight for me. Any service you want to sugest which can drop me at an earlier time to airport?

Comment: I disagree, I was in KEF airport in late June for an early morning flight and getting through security was a breeze. And there are no traffic jams to speak of in Reykjavik.